# Django - invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have the following code

models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

views:

```
def index(request):
    itemlist=Item.objects.all()
    return render(request,"items/index.html",{"itemlist":itemlist})

def details(request,item_id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item,pk=item_id)
    return render(request,"items/details.html",{"item":item})

def new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "create" in request.POST:
            newitemform = NewItemForm(request.POST)
            if newitemform.is_valid():
                cd = newitemform.cleaned_data
                Item.objects.create(name=cd["name"],price=cd["price"])
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("main:index"))

    else:
        newitemform = NewItemForm()

    return render(request,"tags/new.html",{"newitemform":newitemform})
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",
        url(r'^$',views.index,name="index"),
        url(r'^(?P<item_id>\w+)/$',views.details,name="details"),
        url(r'^new/$',views.new,name="new")
        )
```

forms:

```
class NewItemForm(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField(max_length=70)                     
    price=forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
```

and when I call the 'new' view from the 'index' view I keep getting the error:

ValueError at /main/new/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'new'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

you could post the whole error and traceback ... but at a guess

```
url(r'^(?P<item_id>\w+)/$',views.details,name="details"), #<- is the problem
url(r'^new/$',views.new,name="new")
```

since `"new"` matches `"\w+"` ... you can resolve this simply by swapping  those two lines

```
url(r'^new/$',views.new,name="new")
url(r'^(?P<item_id>\w+)/$',views.details,name="details"), #<- is the problem
```

Comment: I solved the problem. You pointed to the right place, but the problem was not that ;). I was using \w+ when I should be using \d+, because that variable was supposed to be an int, not a string

Comment: well the problem really was that then ... I figured you had good reason for using a string there , and just assumed new was not an argument you wanted ... I could have guessed that you wanted an int but that would have directly countermanded what you had, while my answer preserved the rest of your functionality